# The session does not get the new value

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webmethod

The session does not get the new value[image]

object reference not set to instance of an object

Answer (score 2):

`Session` is null.

Use:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable sessions on your web method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public bool SearchCOurses(int level, string keywords) {
    ...
}
```